# Complete task planner flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate, microsoft-planner

SharePoint list item has 5 actions, which are sent to a planner task with flow. No issues here.

Next flow, when a task completed change column status to *completed*. The issue is, if only one action is completed, it changes the status of the column. Columns status should only be updated if all 5 actions are completed.

How could I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Use **And** operator inside **Condition** action. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to **Condition** action in your flow and you want to execute **If yes** block only if all 5 conditions are true,

You need to use **And** operator inside **Condition** action instead of "Or".